# Exposing database as a web-service: design

Tags: java, database, web-services, crud

I am building a web-service that will publicly expose the database operations. Those operations represent a database **API** in a way.

Now what I would like to know, how should the design of such **API** look like? Should the methods for all database interactions be in the same class?

In particular scenario, I have 3 DB tables: `User`, `Country`, `Town`. Now, do I write methods like

- `fetchAllUsers()`
- `fetchUserById(int id)`
- `fetchUserByName(String name)`
- `saveUser(User user)...`
- `fetchAllCountries()`
- `fetchCountryById(int id)`
- `fetchCountryByCode(String code)`
- `fetchAllTowns()`
- `fetchTownById(int id) ...`
- etc.

**Question 1:** It is a whole lot of methods. If there are more than 3 classes, there will be vast number of such methods. Is that really how it is being done?

**Question 2:** Should all of those methods be situated in the same class, let's call it some `DatabaseAPI.java`? So that the web-service, no matter what operation the user requests, always looks for that operation in the`DatabaseAPI.java` where all such methods are, or should I organize them in a different way?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend you break the methods between classes for each database table. That isn't always possible when you are frequently joining between tables, though.

Comment: @cricket_007 So far I have a business layer where my classes are. Do you suggest writing a DAL for every single class with those database interaction methods? For example, writing a TownDAL.java which will only provide methods like fetchById(int id), fetchByName(String name) etc?

Comment: That's my opinion, yes. I'm sure there are other ways to structure the code.